# Add projects to gitbub with netbeans

Tags: git, version-control, netbeans, github

Does anyone now how to add my projects from within netbeans (version 6.9.1.) To github?
I can't find any information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Netbeans [git](http://nbgit.org/) module [doesn't have support](http://code.google.com/p/nbgit/issues/detail?id=41&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Component%20Owner%20Summary) for push. So I don't think this is possible.

Comment: So what would then be the best way to use github and netbeans together?

Comment: perhaps use another GUI git application ? Which OS @sanders

Answer (score -1):

See the official screencast at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/github_nb_screencast.html